# Calculating the net charge of DNA oligo

Tags: formal-charge, dna-rna, electrostatic-energy, electrical-properties

How can I calculate the net charge of a DNA oligo? I have a bunch of different sized oligos (vary from 9 to 50nt long) which I am using for microscopy (DNA-PAINT) and I need to know their charges depending on the sequence. How can I calculate that?

To top things up, the oligos often have modifications: azide on one end and a fluorophore on the other end. For example: 5' Cy5 TTATACATACTTA 3' azide.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The charge is usually dependent on the pH of the solution. More information is required on this.

Comment: Negative charge at neutral pH is roughly equal to the number of nucleotides in the oligo. The length of single-stranded oligos is measured in nucleotides (nt), not base pairs (bp).

Comment: @BuckThorn pH is between 6.8 and 7.5